# Tikz relative positioning with ++

Tags: tikz-pgf

The red rectangle is in the correct position, but I need the blue ones to be 4 and 8mm to the right of the red on the same height (not below, as my code makes it).

What is wrong with my use of ++?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Tikztezt}
\begin{figure}\flushleft

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{bar1mm/.style={shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=1mm, anchor=west}}
\node[bar1mm, fill=red] at (10mm,10mm) {}
++(4mm,0mm) node[bar1mm] {}
++(4mm,0mm) node[bar1mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I actually need to position a lot of nodes, and the code here is just a minimum workable example, which is why I prefer ++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first node uses its own `at` mechanism such that the path pen is still at `(0,0)`. This is because `\node` is (roughly) short for `\path node`. And every path automatically assumes to be at `\pgfpointorigin` at the start.

You can start your path as

```
\path (10mm,10mm) node[bar1mm,...
```

Then the pen is moved to `(10mm,10mm)` and the rest follows.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[bar1mm/.style={shape=rectangle, fill=blue, minimum height=5mm, minimum width=1mm, anchor=west}]
\node (o) at (0,0) {O};
\path (10mm,10mm)node [bar1mm, fill=red]  {}
++(4mm,0mm) node[bar1mm] {}
++(4mm,0mm) node[bar1mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]